# Why cant rails 3 find my association when using has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have the following models:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :players

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams, :through => :players
end
```

And when I do the following on front end

```
<%= @team.users %>
```

I get the exception:

> Could not find the association :players in model Team

And when I try:

```
<%= @team.players %>
```

I get the following:

> undefined method 'players' for #

Any clue what may be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you also need to include your join models, like so

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  has_many :users, :through => :players

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  has_many :teams, :through => :players
end
```